# refactoring legacy spring framework 4.0.1 to support spring boot RestControllers

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a broader sense I'd like to be able to have the advantages of spring boot in a traditional "do everything by hand" spring framework project. Since the JPA repositories, services and providers are written by hand so far, a soft switch-over to the spring boot way would be perfect. I'd like to use `@RestController("mymodel")` type annotations.

```
<spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<org.springframework.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
<org.springframework.data.spring-data-jpa.version>1.5.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.spring-data-jpa.version>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: If there's a guide / series of steps that can be used to add spring boot to a regular spring framework 4.0.1 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an existing `spring 4` project, you can just starting using the  new features. `spring boot` introduces a lot of new auto configuration as well as project starters. If you have existing code you can probably just start by simplify/cleaning up some pre-4.0 wiring. `boot` builds on a lot of this. You can browse through the main features in the spring boot reference guide [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_learning_about_spring_boot_features).

In the case of `@RestController`, this builds on `Spring MVC`. Take a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) part of the guide to see what machinery is behind the usage of this annotation.